# jQuery Validation plugin - multiple forms on page - only validate the submitted one

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the great jQuery Validation plugin - http://jqueryvalidation.org/ and need to use a class- to validate a form.

The thing is there could be more than one form on a page with and they would have that same class. When I try to submit one form the plugin validates both forms instead of just the one being submitted.

Does anyone know a work around for this? I've tried adding a randomly generated ID to each form and grabbing that in a submit event but the validation plugin fails silently when I try it.

Cheers!

Update:

```
//validate and submit form
jQuery('.js-booking-form').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //Submit Booking Request via AJAX
  }
});
```

and sample HTML both forms are pretty much identical so here's shortened version:

```
<form class="js-nudge-booking-form nudge-vertical-booking-form" data-ajaxurl="http://localhost/site/ajax/">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="client-name">
 <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: add some code maybe and show us your efforts? I'd rather correct some of your lines than writing the complete code myself for you...

Comment: I know the plugin works with multiple forms on the same page.  Can you add in your HTML and your JS so we can see what is going on

Comment: @cari Updated the question with sample code, I wasn't expecting you to write any code for me. Thanks

Comment: @JoeCianflone Added sample code. I'm sure it works with multiple forms but I don't think it does if both forms are using the same identifier which in my case is a class.

Comment: To add to that @JoeCianfloneI believe the plugin will only validate the first form it finds on the page and not the submitted one.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted - Using each to loop through the forms and referencing the form to validate through the "this" keyword works.

Found the solution here: http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/02/jquery-validation-plugin-with-multiple-forms/ I can't really figure out why it works as I would think that it would be telling the plugin to validate each form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you HAVE to use Class name to validate. A quick and simple solution would be to have separate ID for each form and reference the form by ID

```
<form id="form1" class="yourclass">...</form>
<form id="form2" class="yourclass">...</form>
```

To validate a specific form:

```
$('#form1').validate({...});
```

By referencing your form by class, you will always get 2 form objects returned because both form have the same class name. And Hence your current dilemma. Now you can get around that, but that would involve either modify jquery.validate code itself or validate handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the forms are output from a WordPress plugin's shortcode I'm developing. I can add a randomly generated ID to each copy of the form output by the plugin but I won't know the ID. I'm trying to find a workaround but so far what I've tried isn't working.

Comment: This solution works - http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/02/jquery-validation-plugin-with-multiple-forms/

Comment: that solution should also validate both forms - "each" keyword. I thought you were trying to not validate both forms.

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't validate the first form that I'm not submitting, it works but I can't figure out why.